# Cannot connect Teamcity to Team Foundation Service / TFSPreview.com - Error "You must update your client with the Forward Compatibility Update"

Tags: tfs, teamcity, teamcity-7.0, azure-devops

Teamcity 7.1.3 on a Windows 7 64 bit build machine

The box is currently happily building VS2008 projects stored in a TFS2005 server, but am trying out VS2012 projects stored in TFSPreview / TF Service, and I cannot get past setting up the VCS root.

On clicking Test Connection, I get the following..

```
Test connection failed in VS2012 Test against TFSPreview :: VS2012 - Build 
Configuration for Hello World. TFS failed. ExitCode: 1
stdout: TFS Native Verifier v7.1 Copyright (C) 2006-2012 JetBrains s.r.o.
Running under .NET Framework 4.0.30319.17929
INFO  - Use Tfs from JetBrains.TeamCity.Tfs.Tfs8Accessor
TFS Native Accessor v7.1 Copyright (C) 2006-2012 JetBrains s.r.o.
INFO  - Connecting to server https://[our TFS Area].visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection
Connection test:
  Server='https://[our TFS Area].visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection'
  Username='[username email]'
  Root='$/Hello World'
ERROR - The request failed with HTTP status 400: TF253023: You must update your client   
with the Forward Compatibility Update in order to connect to the Team Foundation Server 
that you selected. To obtain this update, go to the Microsoft Web site:   
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=166482.
System.Exception: The request failed with HTTP status 400: TF253023: You must update 
your client with the Forward Compatibility Update in order to connect to the Team 
Foundation Server that you selected. To obtain this update, go to the Microsoft Web 
site: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=166482. ---> System.Net.WebException: The 
request failed with HTTP status 400: TF253023: You must update your client with the 
Forward Compatibility Update in order to connect to the Team Foundation Server that you 
selected. To obtain this update, go to the Microsoft Web site: 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=166482.
```

On running the installer specified in the link however, I get the following message:

```
The upgrade patch cannot be installed by the windows installer service because the   
program to be upgraded may be missing, or the upgrade patch may update a different 
version of the program. Verify that the program to be upgraded exists on your computer 
and that you have the correct upgrade patch.
```

I'm therefore stuck. :(

I've also installed Team Foundation Explorer from the VS2005 TFS tfc directory with the aim of enabling me to run the original installer in the link in the error.. but still the same error.

How can I get past this error?

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you using the TFS 2008 version of Team Explorer to connect to TFS? If so have you installed Visual Studio 2008 SP1. The forward compatability updates for all versions of VS require SP1 to be applied before you can install them.

Comment: @James, I hadn't, no. Prior to attempting to connect to tfspreview/ tf service we were / are (still) using TFS2005 to hold VS2008 projects, so I had installed that version as we haven't got anything to do with TFS2008 installed anywhere. Is this wrong?
We have VS2008 on the Build Server in order to create project setup kits, and this is indeed at SP1.

Comment: It looks like TFS thinks you are trying to connect with an older version of Team Explorer. But it also looks like Jetbrains provide a native plugin for TFS. You could try installing Team Explorer 2012 on to the build server, but that's probably not going to work. You could at least use it to test connectivity from the server to TFS but I don't think that's the issue

Comment: Yep, Team Explorer 2012 now installed on the machine and can connect to the TF Service area, so connectivity isn't the issue, as you had guessed. Also applied the TFSIntegration Plugin though if I'm honest I don't really know what that does. Whatever, still in the same situation whereby testing connection in VCS Root wants me to install the FCU, but I can't install the FCU as it doesn't think the underlying software exists to update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeamCity 7.1.4 adds support for tfsPreview.com, according to the [TeamCity Blog](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2013/02/07/teamcity-7-1-4-build-24331-is-ready/)

Comment: Worked for me on version 8. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446930/conecting-teamcity-to-tfs/18695231#18695231 for details

Comment: Accepting this as answer as time has passed since my original accepted answer which was written at the time of 7.1.3. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

OK, basically this doesn't work yet.
As I type this the most up-to-date version of TeamCity is 7.1.3, and JetBrains have come back to me stating that..

```
7.1.3 supports local TFS 2012 installations. 
What we do not support is Windows Live authentication that is used for cloud instances of TFS.
```

Using the alternate credentials also doesn't work in 7.1.3, so basically it looks like a no-no in the current version.

JetBrains state that it's scheduled to be fixed in version 8, but depending on the fix, it *may* be backported to 7.x. If so I'll update this accordingly.

Comment: I'm still having the same issue in TeamCity 8.1.4.  Did you ever get an update from TeamCity or have a bug tracking number?

Comment: @Japster24 Alas I'm not able to be much help here... :(  Due to third party components that couldn't be loaded into the cloud CI system (at the time anyway) we decided to keep TFS on-premesis, so I simply haven't tried it. Original issue logged here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-25149 Interesting it doesn't still work as I was going to revisit this in a month or so...

Comment: @Japster24 looks like it can work with some tweaking after all... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446930/connecting-teamcity-to-tfs