# TFS Azure Service with on prem TeamCity

Tags: tfs, teamcity-7.0, azure-devops

Is it possible to hook up an on premises TeamCity build server to Microsoft's TFS service?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot connect Teamcity to Team Foundation Service / TFSPreview.com - Error "You must update your client with the Forward Compatibility Update"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988453/cannot-connect-teamcity-to-team-foundation-service-tfspreview-com-error-you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: [JetBrains has released a new version which now supports Team Foundation Service](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2013/02/07/teamcity-7-1-4-build-24331-is-ready/comment-page-1/#comment-38321). The version is 7.1.4.

---

Currently not. [TeamCity does not support the new basic authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14143020/736079). [Version 8](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Supported+Platforms+and+Environments) is supposed to fix this.