# Connecting TeamCity to TFS

Tags: tfs, authorization, teamcity, azure-devops

I'm struggling trying to connect my TeamCity project to my TFS project. I tried a bunch of stuff, but I always get the same error:

```
TFS failed. ExitCode: 111, command: C:\TeamCity\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\plugins\tfs\bin\tfs-native.exe @@C:\TeamCity\temp\TC-TFS-25-7939_109\command.params, in file: {https://budiedimas.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/TesteTeamCity, /hash:S, /noProxy, C:\TeamCity\temp\TC-TFS-25-7939_108.result, ConnectionTest, $/TesteTeamCity/TesteTeamCity}, completed in: 1 second(s)
stdout: TFS Native Verifier v8.0 Copyright (C) 2006-2013 JetBrains s.r.o.
Running under .NET Framework 4.0.30319.18052
INFO  - 
INFO  - Use Team Explorer 2012
INFO  - 
TFS Native Accessor v8.0 Copyright (C) 2006-2013 JetBrains s.r.o.
INFO  - Connecting to server https://budiedimas.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/TesteTeamCity
INFO  - WebProxy is disabled
Connection test:
  Server='https://budiedimas.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/TesteTeamCity'
  Root='$/TesteTeamCity/TesteTeamCity'
ERROR - TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://budiedimas.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/TesteTeamCity.
System.Exception: TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://budiedimas.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/TesteTeamCity. ---> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServerUnauthorizedException: TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://budiedimas.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/TesteTeamCity.
   em Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.EnsureTokenProvider(HttpWebResponse webResponse)
   em Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.SendRequest()
   em Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpRequestChannel.Request(TfsMessage message, TimeSpan timeout)
   em Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.Invoke(TfsClientOperation operation, Object[] parameters, TimeSpan timeout, Object[]& outputs)
   em Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.Registration.GetRegistrationEntries(String toolId)
   em Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.RegistrationProxy.GetRegistrationEntries(String toolId)
   em Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.RegistrationService.GetInstanceId()
   em Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.RegistrationService.get_InstanceClientCacheDirectory()
   em Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.RegistrationService..ctor(TfsTeamProjectCollection tfsObject)
   em Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection.CreateServiceProxy(Type serviceType)
   em Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection.GetServiceInstance(Type serviceType, Object serviceInstance)
   em Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.GetService(Type serviceType)
   em Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.PreFrameworkServerDataProvider.FindServiceLocation(String serviceType, String toolId)
   em Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.PreFrameworkServerDataProvider.LocationForCurrentConnection(String serviceType, Guid serviceIdentifier)
   em Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.EnsureProviderConnected()
   em JetBrains.TeamCity.Tfs.Command.Do() na c:\BuildAgent\work\23f504c63c17dfdf\TfsNativeAccessor\src\Command.cs:linha 28
   em JetBrains.TeamCity.Tfs.Program.Main(String[] args) na c:\BuildAgent\work\23f504c63c17dfdf\TfsNativeAccessor\src\Program.cs:linha 134
   --- Fim do rastreamento de pilha de exce‡äes internas ---
   em JetBrains.TeamCity.Tfs.Program.Main(String[] args) na c:\BuildAgent\work\23f504c63c17dfdf\TfsNativeAccessor\src\Program.cs:linha 438
```

I always get the error:

> 'You are not authorized to access /DefaultCollection/'

I have admin rights in everything on the TFS and I don't know if I'm missing some authorizantion configuration on the TeamCity.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Did you enable alternate credentials? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2013/01/07/how-to-connect-to-tf-service-without-a-prompt-for-liveid-credentials.aspx

Comment: Yes... I did.. Still gives the same problem

Comment: Hi Victor, I'm having exactly the same problem. Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 12):

I finally managed to get this working in the latest version of teamcity (which for me is 8.0.3) but apparently this has been working since version [7.1.4](http://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2013/02/teamcity-7-1-4-build-24331-is-ready/).

1. [First configure alternate credentials in TFS](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2012-aug-27/)
   (profile -> credentials -> enable alternate credentials)
2. Then in TeamCity

   - Use the following URL format: **https://{yournamehere}.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection**
   - For the username use the alternate credential name you setup in step 1. BUT put it in the following format "**##LIVE##\usernamehere**" (It actually tells you this below the box, but I somehow missed it first time!)

Hope this helps someone else, as I wasted quite a bit of time on this!

Comment: In addition, don't forget to install Visual Studio Update 1 (or above). It's listed as a requirement in the instruction box Rob mentioned.

Comment: Does the admin of the Hosted TFS have to enter their credentials?

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thanks!  It might've helped if I read that info below the textbox in TeamCity, too.

Comment: The reason you need VS 2012 Update 1 or above is because the API used to connect to TFS was only added in 2012 Update 1 (source: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-20909#)

Answer (score 2):

I've blurred out my url name and username, but I know pictures help a lot of people. This is @Rob Birds solution to the problem.  I can't thank him enough!  Again, **ensure you have at least VisualStudio 2012 Update 1** with Team Explorer installed on the TeamCity build server and agent.  After updating Visual Studio (if needed), you'll need to restart the TeamCity build server and build agent as well.

[image]

Comment: +1 Always helps to have a picture - Nice one Jasper!

Comment: In addition, I requested an update to their documentation and they followed up with the changes very quickly.  

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Team+Foundation+Server#TeamFoundationServer-HostedTFSLogin

I love the JetBrains team.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its a cache issue. Restarting the Team city service worked for me