# Teamcity setup with Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: tfs, teamcity, azure-devops

I have been trying to integrate Team city with Visual Studio Team Services and keep getting this error, can anyone help.

I have enabled basic authentication in tfs by going to
 TFS -> Profile -> basic authentication.

Trying to create a Create Project From URL on TeamCity, Getting error on below setting.

Settings

Repository URL: *   https://xxxxxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/AddBk

Error

> Could not create a project by specified URL, URL is not recognized

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connect TeamCity to Visual Studio Online](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24365220/connect-teamcity-to-visual-studio-online)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the repository as including the collection but not the project.

So http://mytfs.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection as the repository and then you can specify the $/myTeamProject/[path] in the "root" variable.

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Team+Foundation+Server

For credentials I would recommend that you use the server account credentials rather than local user ones. You can get the server credentials through the API or by using the [TFS Credential Viewer](http://nakedalm.com/getting-service-account-vso-tfs-service-credential-viewer/).

Comment: And install team explorer 2012 and Visual studio update 4 on the machine. And use ##LIVEID##\alternativecred instead if just your live ID.

Comment: Thanks #jessehouwing #mrhinsh, combining both of your suggestion got me there.

Comment: Depends on your system. Works fine on Win8 or Win10 with VS 2013. That's my current test matrix. You are welcome to download the code and do your own thing...