# Can't setup VCS Roots for TFS Online in TeamCity

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, continuous-integration, teamcity

I'm attempting to setup a TeamCity project on our build server. Our VCS repository is on VisualStudio.com. I set the correct URL with a valid username/password. but, i keep getting "TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://XXX.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection". I know the URL, username, and password are correct. I use it every day to access the code from withing VS. I have even used other username/passwords of other developers on the team and none work.

I have the TFS Settings as such in Edit VCS Root:
URL: https://XXX.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection
Root: $/IRM/Release
Username and Password are set to a valid username/password.

I used Fiddler to view raw data on the request and the stacktrace shows:

```
jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.VcsRootVcsException: Failed to get current version of TFS root. TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://XXX.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection. 
at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsChangesStatesCollector.createRootException(VcsChangesStatesCollector.java:61)
at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsChangesStatesCollector.getCurrentState(VcsChangesStatesCollector.java:34) 
at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsChangesStatesCollector.access$100(VcsChangesStatesCollector.java:5) 
at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsChangesStatesCollector$2.run(VcsChangesStatesCollector.java:6) 
at jetbrains.buildServer.util.NamedThreadFactory.executeWithNewThreadName(NamedThreadFactory.java:89) 
at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsChangesStatesCollector.doCollectStates(VcsChangesStatesCollector.java:3)
at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsChangesStatesCollector.access$000(VcsChangesStatesCollector.java:32) 
at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsChangesStatesCollector$1.run(VcsChangesStatesCollector.java:1) 
at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsChangesLoaderImpl$ImmediateFutureExecService$1.call(VcsChangesLoaderImpl.java:1)
at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.ImmediateFuture.get(ImmediateFuture.java:48) 
at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.ImmediateFuture.get(ImmediateFuture.java:55) 
at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsChangesStatesCollector.collectStatesForAllRoots(VcsChangesStatesCollector.java:51)
at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsChangesStatesCollector.getCurrentStateSnapshot(VcsChangesStatesCollector.java:60)
at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsChangesFetcher.createTasksToLoadChangesForInstances(VcsChangesFetcher.java:61)
at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsChangesSyncFetcher.loadChangesNoLocking(VcsChangesSyncFetcher.java:99) 
at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsChangesLoaderImpl.tryLoadChanges(VcsChangesLoaderImpl.java:16) 
at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.VcsModificationChecker$CollectChangesAction$1.run(VcsModificationChecker.java:2)
at jetbrains.buildServer.util.NamedThreadFactory.executeWithNewThreadName(NamedThreadFactory.java:89) 
at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.VcsModificationChecker$CollectChangesAction.run(VcsModificationChecker.java:6)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Not sure if the "Failed to get current version of TFS root" is a hint or not. But, I have no clue what to try at this point.  Any suggestions?

******* NOTE: 
I have installed TeamCity on 3 other machine and was able to connect to our VisualStudio online account with only one of them. All machines are using the same username/password and all machines are behind the same firewall. the machine that can connect is on Windows 7 Professional SP1. which is the same as one of the machines that can't connect. I have even tried moving the of the non-working Windows 7 Professional machine outside of the firewall but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here:

[Connecting TeamCity to TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446930/connecting-teamcity-to-tfs/18695231#18695231)

...There's an image I entered.  The answer depends on what version of TeamCity you're running. It changed slightly, but the post above should help.